# Android MultiPart Entity Causing App Crash

Tags: java, android, apache, android-asynctask

I am currently working on an android app that will allow the user to upload images to my server. I am new to android development so currently facing issues with sending the file to the server while using the Http MultiPartEntity

Given below is the code I am using for uploading the file to the server
    private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        //Change URL here
        String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = SERVER_SUBMIT_URL;

        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

            File file1 = new File(filePath1);
            FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
            reqEntity.addPart("image1", bin1);

            //Extras
            reqEntity.addPart("command", new StringBody("uploadImages"));

            post.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            resEntity = response.getEntity();

            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            return responseString;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //Assuming JSON response From server
        // {"status": true, "ideaID" : 1}
        try{
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            boolean status = json.getBoolean("status");
            if(status){
                showToast("Successfully Uploaded Images");

            }else{
                showToast("Image Uploading Failed");
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Image Uploading Failed");
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result + " " + e.getMessage());
        }
        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

I figured that the line "HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);" is where the app just crashed.

Here is the error that is shown in the log.

```
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway /AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.toString(ContentType.java:153)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.<init>(MultipartFormEntity.java:53)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:236)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.getEntity(MultipartEntity.java:119)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.isChunked(MultipartEntity.java:138)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:79)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:167)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:413)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.grow.dubaiway.ImageActivity$UploadFileToServer.uploadFile(ImageActivity.java:197)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.grow.dubaiway.ImageActivity$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(ImageActivity.java:156)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.grow.dubaiway.ImageActivity$UploadFileToServer.doInBackground(ImageActivity.java:137)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
11-22 00:24:41.341 8203-11792/com.example.grow.dubaiway E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Could really use some help on the issue.
Ive checked other posts but they didn't work for me.

Ive included the following libraries from the apache website.
httpclient-4.5.1.jar
httpclient-cache-4.5.1.jar
httpcore-4.4.3.jar
httpmime-4.5.1.jar

This is what my gradle file looks like
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.neeraj.imageapp"
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
      release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }

   packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
       exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `HttpClient` method is deprecated in coming version so why not using `Volley` or `HttpURLConnection` for making http requests

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Volley uses Apache's library too :)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the feedback. Although, i fixed the problem by using older versions of the libraries. Switching to version 4.3.1 solved the problem for me, and now it works perfectly. Was able to use a multipart entity with a progress publisher as well. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try using MultipartEntityBuilder

```
try
{
    File file1 = new File(filePath1);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    MultipartEntityBuilder entBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    entBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entBuilder.addBinaryBody(file1.getName(), file1);

    //Extras
    entBuilder.addPart("command", new StringBody("uploadImages"));

    /*
        If you need to send more files...

        entBuilder.addBinaryBody(file2.getName(), file2);
        entBuilder.addBinaryBody(file3.getName(), file3);
        ...
    */

    HttpEntity entity = entBuilder.build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
    post.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

    return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You need to add dependencies in gradle

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
    exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
}
```

But I think that it would be better removing http apache dependencies (like HttpClient) from your code as Google removed it from Android 6 (api 23)

> Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If
>   your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or
>   higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more
>   efficient because it reduces network use through transparent
>   compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption